# Opening Selenium Browser in a JavaFX WebView

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javafx

I want to know if there is anyway I can open up the Selenium WebDriver in a WebView rather than the default behavior of opening in a new window. If not is there anyway I can get the same functionality (Being able to press buttons, and fill text fields) through the JavaFX WebView.

Comment: JavaFX's WebView sucks. I've tried to load a simple unicode web page and it bugs me with square symbols. It also behaves strangely when I dynamically create it inside an existing components. It flashes for a millisecond.